# Error_renaming_columns_in_a_data_frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I have a data frame in R with columns date, loc.ret and hedged.ret

I am trying to rename the columns using following code

```
as %>% rename("mom.loc.ret"="loc.ret","mom.hedged.ret"="hedged.ret")
```

I am getting the following error

```
Error in rename(., mom.loc.ret = "loc.ret", mom.hedged.ret = "hedged.ret") : 
  unused arguments (mom.loc.ret = "loc.ret", mom.hedged.ret = "hedged.ret")
```

Whats the possible error here

Comment: Please add the data. You can paste the output of `head(as)`

Comment: There are few scenarios where you can get this error. 1 If you wrote a function `rename` that masks the `dplyr::rename` function. Or 2. You loaded another package after dplyr that contains a `rename` function. In both cases, you can solve the issue by explicitly calling the `rename` function from the dplyr package using the scope resolution operator ie `%>% dplyr::rename(...)` or restart your Rstudio

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `rename_with()`to rename with a function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

as |>
    rename_with(.cols = ends_with("ret"), .fn = \(x) glue("mom.{x}"))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will rename all the columns that end with ret. Suppose OP is only interested in the two columns above, this solution does not answer the problem OP is facing

Comment: the key in my answer was `rename_with`. I used `ends_with`, but the OP may use whatever tidy-select statment they prefer for their use-case.

Comment: I should acknowledge my answer is not all that useful as you pointed out, @Onyambu, thank you.

Comment: It is useful.  w